# Why can't I see my database when creating File DSN for Azure SQL?

Tags: azure, ms-access, azure-sql-database

I am trying to set up a File DSN in order to export data from a local Access database to a cloud Azure SQL database.

I have followed the instructions [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/administer-odbc-data-sources-b19f856b-5b9b-48c9-8b93-07484bfab5a7#bm1) to create the DSN.

It "works" in so far as when I test the connection to the database it connects successfully.

However, it defaults the database to "master", whereas I want to use "mydatabase". The Change Default Database dropdown only has master, mydatabase doesn't appear so I can't change it.

So if I use the default settings I get the error that CREATE TABLE is denied in master.

I edited the File DSN via notepad in to include the line "DATABASE=mydatabase", but then I get the error: "Reference to database and/or server name in 'master...sysdatabases' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

How can I set this up to specify the correct database and have it work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in my comment on @Gustav's answer, the resolution to this should anyone have a similar problem is actually to create the File DSN direct from the Access Export wizard and not using the Administrative Tools wizard per the link in my question.

The Access Export wizard allows you to select the driver: ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server and not the driver SQL Server.

(The reason I knew this was the driver to use is because on the Azure portal under Connection Strings > ODBC it shows that driver.)

Some other points: don't copy your server name from the azure portal, again use what it says in the connection string. (i.e. rather than {yourserver}.database.windows.net you use tcp:{yourserver}.database.windows.net,1433 and the username is also {username]@{yourserver} and not just {username}

The Access Wizard will then allow you to change the default database away from master.

Answer (score 0):

You don't reveal your connection string, but *Server* requires an extended syntax with AzureSQL, as does *Uid*, like:

```
"ODBC;Driver=SQL Server Native Client 13.0;Server=tcp:b8uroj8q5d.database.windows.net;Database=YourDatabase;Uid=username@b8uroj8q5d;Pwd=YourPassword;Encrypt=yes"
```

Comment: But there's nowhere that takes a connection string? I used the create DSN wizard. I'm familiar with the principle of the connection sting and how I'd use it if I was doing .net to sql etc. but this is exporting from Access?

Comment: If, as you state, you use a File DSN, this file contains the connections string. It's a straight text file.

Comment: It doesn't contain a connection string, in the format/sense that you mention. It's a series of newline key value pairs similar to the connection string in a different format. But my whole point is that when I use the DSN wizard, it doesn't let me choose anything other than master, and when I edit the DSN to have database=mydatabase (equivalent to the connection string bit as you've mentioned), I get an error.

Comment: Then the account you are using probably hasn't been granted access to that database. Use _SQL Server Management Studio_ and your admin account to sort it out.

Comment: The account is the server admin I created when creating the database in Azure. I'm not even using SSMS I'm using Azure Data Studio.

Comment: OK. I'm not familiar with ADS, only SSMS.

Comment: I don't think ADS or SSMS matters as @Dave can use SSMS, ADS, PowerShell, etc. in order to verify connectivity with the specified account. This could be an MS Access issue, maybe due to an old version.

Comment: @DanGuzman: Hardly. Access doesn't control how rights are granted. Could be a driver issue though, but Dave doesn't reveal much.

Comment: @Gustav, id didn't mean to suggest the client controlled the rights. Just that a successful connection from any client from the same machine would verify both connectivity and permissions.

Comment: I can connect, the issue is the wizard won't show me any other databases, and changing the name via notepad throws an error

Comment: Actually the issue appears to be the difference between creating a File DSN using the Adminstrative tools wizard, and using the wizard through the Access Export wizard. The Admin tools only uses the SQL Server driver, whereas you actually need to use ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server. You get this option when creating the DSN using Access, and it works

Comment: Yes. See my answer, please.